# mydomain.com is listed in DBL. What is alternative to send email from Magento Store

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

Don't know why but My Magento store Domain is listed in DBL. and my customers are unable to receive email.

But i am in search of any good tool/extension which i can use to send Order Emails. I have used the SMTP pro but it receive email inside Dashboard only .

Answer (score 0):

you could check out mandrill: http://mandrill.com/

then you have extensions to help integrate: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-extension.html

one word of warning though is that Mandrill's servers can also be blacklisted as it naturally opens you up to how others have used it in the past. Therefore it's best to set up SPF records on your own domain usually, if yours is blacklisted I would look at fixing that.